# Where to download NAT Track Message (original and official source)?

Tags: air-traffic-control, flight-path, transatlantic, nat

I am studying about North Atlantic tracks. 
I know the message is usually distributed to interested parties via AFTN and is published by Shanwick or Gander. I would also like to get such information from the same source.

Where can I download NAT Track Messages in their original format (I guess it is the AFTN Message Format)?

Note: I want the official and original message possibly. I don't want other websites that show me NOTAMs or other formats that are not official. I am interested in the original message.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Where to download NATs (North Atlantic Tracks) information?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/where-to-download-nats-north-atlantic-tracks-information) You mustn't add a new post when you actually need to edit your initial question. Please use the `edited on ...` link at the bottom of your [initial post](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/where-to-download-nats-north-atlantic-tracks-information).