# How are NATs connected to European Airways?

Tags: air-traffic-control, navigation, flight-planning, transatlantic, nat

The *North Atlantic Tracks* connect Northern Europe to North America. To enter/exit *NAT*s over North America, the *North American Routes* (*NAR*s) are used.

[image]

**Questions**:
What about the European side? What are the rules to enter/exit *NAT*s? What airways must be flown? Can I find the official information written anywhere?

**Note**: Ideally I would like to find a list of routes (directs?) that suggests the pair of waypoints linking the generic NAT and the european airways system. In the past *North Atlantic European Routing Scheme* (*NERS*) was used but nowadays it appears they have been dismissed.

Comment: Partly answered (see [this map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C4546.jpg) for instance) in: [Where to download NATs (North Atlantic Tracks) information?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/32852/where-to-download-nats-north-atlantic-tracks-information)

Comment: @mins the question is not duplicate since my question asks for information about the part of airspace connecting the NATs and the european airwways. I am not asking for NATs information where to download it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no equivalent in Europe to the North Atlantic Routes, you simply file direct from point to point.
This is the routing for a flight on Wednesday 18th of January, 2017 (DAL4).

```
KJFK
MERIT HFD PUT WITCH ALLEX N263A JOOPY NATS RESNO NATS NETKI NIBOG REMSI UL603 SOGPO UT149 OTSOP T149 LIPMI T150 ROLIS
EDDF
```

You see that the route terminates **NAT S** at **NETKI NIBOG REMSI** which are directs, until the flight joins the upper airway **UL603** at **REMSI**.

Here is the routing in [SkyVector](https://skyvector.com/?ll=55.00114549238658,-10.001953122708564&chart=304&zoom=11&fpl=%20KJFK%20MERIT%20HFD%20PUT%20WITCH%20ALLEX%20N263A%20JOOPY%20RESNO%20NETKI%20NIBOG%20%20REMSI%20UL603%20SOGPO%20UT149%20OTSOP%20T149%20LIPMI%20T150%20ROLIS%20EDDF).

And here is the screenshot from the [FlightAware](https://de.flightaware.com/live/flight/DAL4/history/20170119/0048Z/KJFK/EDDF) flight.

[image: FlightAware DAL4 flight]
<sup>(Image Source: FlightAware)</sup>

Comment: For some reason SkyVector doesnt like NIBOG.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Flying directs is something I was expecting. However I believe there must be a list of directs that suggests the pair of waypoints linking the generic NAT and the european airways system no?

Comment: The flights on the European side are validated through CFMU for routing and slot management, but essentially, you will not have a list but just need to pass the route through CFMU. If CFMU doesnt object due to restrictions, then you are free to file it. AFAIK.

Comment: What is CFMU and AFAIK? I also suppose that only certain waypoints from the european side may be selected for directs to NATs. Otherwise any waypoint would be acceptable no?

Comment: [CFMU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_flow_management) and AFAIK --> **A**s **F**ar **A**s **I** **K**now

Comment: I also suppose that only certain waypoints from the european side may be selected for directs to NATs. Otherwise any waypoint would be acceptable no?