# North Atlantic Tracks entry and exit points

Tags: waypoint, nat

Are the actual locations of the North Atlantic Tracks entry and exit points published anywhere? I'm looking for definition (latitude, longitude) of the entry and exit points for North Atlantic Tracks.

Comment: [Where to download NATs (North Atlantic Tracks) information?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/32852/3201)

Answer (score 2):

You can find [the routes them selves here](https://flightplandatabase.com/nav/NATS), the start and end points are noted like other airway intersections by phonetic names. You [can look up the names here](https://skyvector.com/) (use world hi maps to see them) for exact locations. For example you can see a route start at TUDEP and if you take a look on SkyVector you will find (lat/long in the top corner):

[image]